# Что за картинка типа аватара на этом сайте?

Tags: графика

Что за картинка типа аватара на этом сайте? Это что-то типа штрих-кода и ее можно прочитать в двоичном формате? Периодически встречаю такие квадраты в инете, но не знаю что это.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Это и есть аватары пользователей. Эти аватары не хранятся у хэшкода или у других сайтов. Они все загружаются централизованно с [http://gravatar.com/](http://ru.gravatar.com/).

Если пользователь не проходил процедуру регистрации на сайте gravatar то в ответ на запрос аватара отправляется специальная картинка которая называется [Identicon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identicon). Эта картинка генерируется на основе md5 хэша email адреса пользователя.

Вот пример запроса к gravatar-овскому серверу:

https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/09d66d951b7163d666cbe4c8c09e37f4?s=128&d=identicon

А теперь попробуйте поменять пару букв или цифр в хэше.

Можно даже так:

https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/hello,world!?s=128&d=identicon

Comment: это означает что у меня красивый имейл)

Answer (score 1):

я думаю это 
http://ru.gravatar.com/